# Convert csh script to bash script with foreach and awk commands

Tags: linux, bash, awk

**Working csh script:**

```
#!/bin/csh
foreach xmlfile ( "`cat ~/reportlist.txt`" )
printf $xmlfile"|"
head -c 1000 $xmlfile | awk -F'[="]' '{print $15,"|",$21}'
end
```

This reads a text file line-by-line and navigates to each file and prints required variables from each file using awk.

I need to perform the same in a bash script. I am new to bash. How can I do this in bash?

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can show you the right way to solve the problem rather than just how to re-implement the wrong way to solve the problem in a different language. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons I say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more correct way to do this (see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)) is

```
while IFS= read -r xmlfile; do
    printf '%s' "$xmlfile"
    head -c 1000 "$xmlfile" | awk -F'[="]' '{print $15,"|",$21}'
done < ~/reportlist.txt
```

Using `awk` to parse XML in this way is fragile, and not recommended. Without seeing the XML in question, though, I cannot recommend a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
set +x
for xmlfile in `cat reportlist.txt`
do
printf $xmlfile"|"
head -c 1000 $xmlfile | awk -F'[="]' '{print $15,"|",$21}'
done
```